# Windows Handling Piped Comands Error Redirection

Tags: windows, scripting, error-handling

Warning: I am no expert on building scripts, and sorry for lousy English.

In an case of generating a CSV from a database query I'm using the following commands.

```
CALL java.exe -classpath ... com.xigole.util.sql.Jisql -user dmfodbc -pf pwd.file -driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver -cstring %constr% -c ; -input 42.sql -formatter csv -delimiter ; 2>>%LOGFILE% | CALL grep -v -e "SELECT right" -e "executing: " -e " rows affect" > %FicheiroR% 2>>%LOGFILE%
```

I'm using windows implementation of grep.

The `2>>%LOGFILE%` in both java and grep command is causing an error message indicating the file is being use by another process.

The Ugly workaround i have came up with is to put grep error redirect to a temporary `%LOGFILE%.aux`

```
java ... | grep ... 2>>%LOGFILE%.aux
type %LOGFILE%.aux >> % %LOGFILE%
del %LOGFILE%.aux
```

What is a better solution?

Comment: Not sure any more of what was appening, but i suspect probably the problem could be solved by using 2>>&1 that redirects standard error to standard output.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this in java, use a scripting language like perl, powershell, vbscript (at least from an admin point of view).  Any of these have excellent database interfaces under windows.  My preference would be powershell.  See this [MS newsgroup post](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.windows.powershell&tid=dda68bb2-ce35-47c4-b6d2-f8c29a7c5be8&p=1) for an example of reading from a database in powershell.